# Len function returns incorrect results

Tags: vba, excel

I have some strange issue with the LEN function. My input is the string "......" for which LEN returns the length of 2. I have no clue why it's happening. Any suggestions?
The code I use is:

```
Function replaceCharWith(ByVal str As String, ByVal chToReplace As String, ByVal ch As String) As String
For i = 1 To Len(str)

    If Mid(str, i, 1) = chToReplace Then
        replaceCharWith = replaceCharWith & ch
    Else
        replaceCharWith = replaceCharWith & Mid(str, i, 1)
    End If
Next
End Function

Sub dotsToSlashes()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection
        c = replaceCharWith(c, ".", "/")
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your string is not "......" but "……". This is 2 times HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS Unicode x2026. Excel replaces ... automatically by … if AutoCorrect Options are default.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use the [Replace Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264409(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: @CoolBlue because only now I know about it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your string is not "......" but "……". This is 2 times HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS Unicode x2026. Excel replaces ... automatically by … if AutoCorrect Options are default.

See example:

```
Sub HorizontalEllipsesTest()

 s = "......"
 MsgBox Len(s)

 s = ChrW(8230) & ChrW(8230) 'x2026 = 8230
 MsgBox s
 MsgBox Len(s)

End Sub
```

Where are the AutoCorrect options? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-are-the-AutoCorrect-options-cb889db0-07f8-400a-b6ef-4192cc05cbc3